# How to import files into R?

Tags: r

I'm a new user to R, sorry if my question is too basic.
I've installed  the newest version of R on windows 7 and as a practice, i tried to open a .txt file using

```
students<-read.table("students.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
```

but there's always an error message as follows:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'students.txt': No such file or directory
```

I've already changed the directory to where the students.txt resides; but it just doesn't work. Please help!

Thank you very much in advance if anyone can help me solve the problem.

Comment: I am running R 2.11.0 on Windows 7 and the function for me for the file chooser is `file.choose()` So your code would look like: students <- read.table(file.choose(), header=T, sep="\t")

Comment: Questions about pure programming aspects of R might better be asked at stackoverflow, there's a larger userbase for now.

Answer (score 24):

There is [**an entire R manual devoted to data import / export questions**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html).

Now, if you fail to specify file name and path correctly, use the `file.choose()` function instead which allows you to point, click and shoot:

```
students<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 9):

The error message is saying that it cannot find the students.txt file.  You should try two things:

1. Call `getwd()` and confirm that the file is in the directory that is returned.
2. Try specifying the full path to the file in your `read.table()` call.

Look at `help("read.table")` for more detail on the function.  You may, for instance, want to change the default to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, depending on your application.

Comment: We should also note for the sake of new users of R in Windows that the directories are provided to setwd() using forward slashes e.g. setwd("c:/temp") not backslashes (as is typical in environments with a DOS lineage).

Comment: Or with double back slashes: `c:\\temp`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org), which I thoroughly recommend, then you can create a Project with it's own directory.  `read.csv` and friends will then read from that directory by default, which makes it all nice and easy.

Answer (score 2):

This works with R:

first copy the table; then open up R and type:

```
c <- read.table("clipboard")
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.